# UIView animateKeyFrames not working as expected

Tags: ios, core-animation

I am trying to animate the plane take off scene. Here i am using the UIView animatekeyFrames method and giving the needed key frames, but the last keyframe is not animating, i am attaching a GIF where you can see the glitch in final translation.

[image: This is how it currently looks]

Here is my entire code for the animation, could anyone help me with what is going wrong here?

```
UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 1.5, delay: 4.0, animations: {
    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.0, relativeDuration: 1.0, animations: {
        self.plane.center.x += 300
        self.plane.center.y -= 60
    })
    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.5, relativeDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        self.plane.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -.pi/16)
    })
    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 1.01, relativeDuration: 0.49, animations: {
        self.plane.center.x += 300
        self.plane.center.y -= 60
    })
}, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`relativeStartTime` and `relativeDuration` must be in the range of **0** and **1**.

See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622554-addkeyframe